# Zendesk and Smooch integration: I can receive SMS in Zendesk but can't reply to the SMS

Tags: sms, slack, zendesk, smooch

As per the question title, I've integrated Twilio and Zendesk with Smooch. I can send SMS to my Twilio number and receive this in Zendesk, however when I reply to the ticket in Zendesk the reply just goes to space and doesn't reach the number that initiated the ticket.

I've removed all integrations in Smooch and added them back in with no success - I have no idea what to. I have upgraded my Twilio account from the trial to a paid one, whereas my Zendesk account is a trial account.

I've tested this to/from SMS using Slack in lieu of Zendesk and I have a similar problem i.e. I receive the SMS in Slack but cannot reply. The only way a reply works is when I use "/sk" followed by the reply. Is there something similar that has to happen when replying to SMS generated tickets in Zendesk?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK so after a bit of investigating what I have found is that the automatic integration Smooch setup in Zendesk didn't work properly. This is because the trigger Smooch applied was based on the incoming SMS having a tag=smooch. The Trigger that was set up was based on the tag=smooch...something else (I can't remember what it was).

I changed the trigger value to be tag=smooch and now I can respond to SMS received in Zendesk.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.
When Smooch configures the trigger on Zendesk that allows the agent to respond to the customer, it doesn't check for equality with "supportkit smooch", it checks whether the ticket has a tag that is "smooch" OR "supportkit".
[image]

So it's unlikely that editing the condition solved the problem, unless it had been previously manually changed for some reason.

Maybe you were just unlucky. If you encountered your issue around August 22, 2016, it's may be that Zendesk had trouble fulfilling trigger actions at that time (https://twitter.com/ZendeskOps/status/767850822038351872).

Alternatively, perhaps you did your initial testing with a Twilio trial account and responded to a number other then the one that was used to set up the account. In that case Twilio will not deliver messages.

Note on /sk:
Using a slash command is the only way for an agent to respond to the customer on Slack, otherwise you're just writing into the Slack channel for your team's benefit. The equivalent to the slash command in Zendesk is just responding to the ticket.